# resolve-url-loader using wrong relative path

Tags: javascript, webpack, sass, primeng

I have a Typescript app compiled with Webpack.
Here is how my scss-files are loaded:

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'resolve-url-loader', 'sass-loader?sourceMap']
},
```

And here is how my fonts are loaded:

```
{
   test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=.+)?$/,
   use: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff'
},

{
   test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=.+)?$/,
   use: 'file-loader'
},
```

Then I have a file `app.scss` with this line:

```
@import "~primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.scss";
```

In `node_modules` in a file called `theme.scss` there is a font import:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('fonts/roboto-v15-latin-regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'),
       url('fonts/roboto-v15-latin-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('fonts/roboto-v15-latin-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('fonts/roboto-v15-latin-regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('fonts/roboto-v15-latin-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('fonts/roboto-v15-latin-regular.svg#Roboto') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

But when I compile I get an error:

```
`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './fonts/roboto-v15-latin-regular.eot'
in 'path_to_project/src/app'`
```

So it seems that the problem is that Webpack looks for the font relative to `app.scss` instead of looking it relative to `theme.scss` imported. This is the problem that `resolve-url-loader` should be solving. You see I already have `resolve-url-loader` configured for scss-files. So what's the problem then?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my problem but this is not the end of the story because the error message I was receiving appears misleading. This is very creepy and this gets in the way of debugging.
I had two problems actually, both leading to this same error message:

- Some scss-files used `roboto` font-family but did not define it at all.
- One file had `@padding-left: 0` instead of `padding-left: 0`. Yes, this somehow led Webpack to not finding the font.

The problems require further investigation. I will return to it when I have more free time.

UPDATE:

Ok. Let's see. Two months have past since I had this issue and my code changed quite a bit. But still. I added the line `@padding-right: 0;` with this evil `@` character to the exact same place where it was 2 months ago. And voila, Webpack reports an error message that it supposedly cannot resolve some kind of font. Indeed fatal syntax errors in SCSS may provoke misleading error messages about unrelated fonts being unresolved. I remove the line and font is readily resolved.
Maybe It should be reported to Webpack team or loader's developers team.

Comment: So how did you solve this issue? I have been having this issue for 2 weeks now and cannot figure it out aside from commenting out primeng css.

Comment: @RockGuitarist1 I wrote an update. I suggest you might recheck syntax of your scss- or css-files.